# Scalala Plotting: Compile Error

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, plot, sbt, scalala

I'm trying to implement the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704647/can-you-recommend-a-charting-library-for-scala/3704974#3704974

I've downloaded and compiled `Scalala` from the git hub and placed the `scalala_2.8.1-1.0.0.RC2-SNAPSHOT.jar` in my `lib` folder (I'm using SBT to do my build). Here's the code:

```
import scalala.library.Plotting
object ScalalaTest extends Application
{

  val x = Plotting.linspace(0,1);
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
[error] /src/main/scala/ScalalaTest.scala:6: value linspace is not a member of object scalala.library.Plotting
[error]   val x = Plotting.linspace(0,1);
[error]                    ^
[error] one error found
```

It looks like my scala compiler recognizes the `scalala` package but doesn't recognize members of `Plotting` (I've tried others besides `linspace`). This is strange because according to [the Scalala API](http://www.scalanlp.org/docs/scalala/0.4.0/), `linspace` is a member of `Plotting`.

Comment: I believe there should be a `scalala` tag but don't have the rep to add it.

Comment: Have you checked the source code? Maybe your version isn't matching the scaladoc version?

Comment: Mmm... funny name for a library. Sounds like an old Spanish song :)

Comment: @Diego Sevilla -- Agreed! It reminds me of "Ding Dong Song" by Günther. What's the Spanish song you're thinking of?

Answer (score 2):

That used to work and was nice and elegant - it seems the [current way](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala/wiki/QuickStart) is:

```
val x = DenseVector.range(0,100) / 100.0;
plot.hold = true
plot(x, x :^ 2)
plot(x, x :^ 3, '.')
xlabel("x axis")
ylabel("y axis")
saveas("lines.png")
```

This needs includes:

```
import scalala.tensor.dense.DenseVector
import scalala.library.Plotting._
```

The SBT dependencies are:

```
  val scalaToolsSnapshots = "Scala Tools Snapshots" at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/"
  val ScalaNLPMaven2 = "ScalaNLP Maven2" at "http://repo.scalanlp.org/repo/"
  val ondex = "ondex" at "http://ondex.rothamsted.bbsrc.ac.uk/nexus/content/groups/public/"

  val scalala = "org.scalala" %% "scalala" % "1.0.0.RC2-SNAPSHOT"
```

Comment: @Johan Prinsloo -- What are the packages to import for this to work?

Comment: Import scalala.tensor.dense._          Tested with 1.0.0.RC2-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @Johan Prinsloo -- There's gotta be more. I'm still getting value not found on `plot`, `xlabel`, and `ylabel`.

Comment: tensor.dense._ is just for the new range method. Include  scalala.library.Plotting._  + whetever else your code needs. I am using: import scalala.tensor.dense._
import scalala.library._
import scalala.library.Library._
import scalala.library.LinearAlgebra._
import scalala.library.Statistics._
import scalala.library.Plotting._
//import scalala.library.Vectors
import scalala.operators.Implicits._

Comment: @Johan Prinsloo -- I think something is wrong with my build. I get: `Vectors is not a member of scalala.library`.

Comment: The easiest way to make sure you get the correct stuff is top simply declare the dependency in a SBT build - I edited to include the correct dependencies - this works in SBT 0.7.7

Answer (score 0):

`linspace` seems to be a member of the trait `Plotting`, not of the companion object. So you'll have to create an instance of `Plotting` (or anything `with Plotting`) in order to access that method.

Comment: `Plotting` has a companion: `object Plotting extends Plotting`. The other subclass is `scalala.Scalala`, which I'm having trouble referencing. The line `import scalala.Scalala` throws the following compiler error: `Scalala is not a member of scalala`.